# how to Assign Image to Custom Drawn SCNShape

Tags: nodes, augmented-reality, arkit, nsbezierpath, sceneview

I have drawn some 2D spheres and added them in the Nodes Array, then I used cylinderNodes to connect the sphere Nodes, It forms a Closed Shape. What I want here is to assign an image to this closed Path.

```
 func DrawPath() {
```

// Ensure there are nodes in the nodesArray

```
   guard !nodesArray.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    // Create a UIBezierPath
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    for (index, child) in nodesArray.enumerated() {
        if index == 0 {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(child.position.x), y: CGFloat(child.position.y)))
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(child.position.x), y: CGFloat(child.position.y)))
        }
    }
    
    // Close the path to create a shape
    path.close()
    // Create an SCNShape
   // let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
```

if I use SCNPlane Instead of SCNShape , I'm getting these results .

```
    `let size = SCNVector3(
        max.x - min.x,
        max.y - min.y,
        max.z - min.z
    )
    
    // Create a plane geometry

    let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(size.x), height: CGFloat(size.z))
    let imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "grass")

    // Apply the material to the plane's geometry
    shape.materials = [imageMaterial]
    // Create an SCNNode with the shape geometry
    
    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
    planeNode.position.z = -2
    arScnView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
      
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

the result i want to achieve:
[image]