# Assign 2d Virtual image to SCNShape drawn using bezierpath

Tags: uiimage, arkit, nsbezierpath

**I have the drawBtn to draw sphere on the plane , then i have the lineNode , that continuously updates the line position according to the user camera so that they might know where they want to add their new sphere to create a shape.**

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController , ARSCNViewDelegate, ARCoachingOverlayViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    var nodes: [SCNNode] = []
    var linenodes : [SCNNode] = []
    var startingNode : SCNNode!
    var lineNode : LineNode!
    
    
    let coachingOverlay = ARCoachingOverlayView()
    var isEditingEnabled = true
    
    var session: ARSession {
        return sceneView.session
    }
    
    // MARK: - View Didload
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //Setup an AR SceneView Session
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session.delegate = self
        let Config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        Config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        sceneView.session.run(Config,  options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

        
        let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(handleTap))
        imageview.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
        imageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }
```

**The Draw btn handles the raycast result and add the nodes to nodes Array ,**
// MARK: - Draw the spheres to create a Shape

```
    @IBAction func DrawBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let screenPoint = CGPoint(x: sceneView.bounds.midX, y: sceneView.bounds.midY)
        guard let raycastQuery = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: screenPoint, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any) else {return}
        let raycastResults = sceneView.session.raycast(raycastQuery)
        
        guard let firstResult = raycastResults.first  else {  return }
      
        
        let position = SCNVector3.positionFrom(matrix: firstResult.worldTransform)
        
        let sphere = SCNSphere(color: .systemBlue, radius: 0.01)
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        
        node.position = position
        
        let lastNode = nodes.last

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        
        // Add the Sphere to the list.
        nodes.append(node)
        
        // Setting our starting point for drawing a line in real time
        self.startingNode = nodes.last

        if lastNode != nil {
            // If there are 2 nodes or more
            
            if nodes.count >= 2 {
                // Create a node line between the nodes
                let LineBetweenNodes = LineNode(from: (lastNode?.position)!,   to: node.position, lineColor: UIColor.systemBlue)
            
                // Add the Node to the scene.
                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(LineBetweenNodes)
               
                
            }
            
        }

        
    }
```

then we have the imageView that the user can assign to the drawn path ,

```
    // MARK: - handle Tap on ImageView

    @objc func handleTap( _ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
        
        if startingNode === nodes.last {
            // Create a line segment from the last node to the first node
            if let firstNode = nodes.first {
                let LineBetweenNodes = LineNode(from: startingNode.position, to: firstNode.position, lineColor: UIColor.systemBlue)
                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(LineBetweenNodes)
             
                //Add Image to the Closed Path
                AddImage()
            }
        }

    }
```

**this is where we have the problem. The path is drawn correctly , it shows the 3d values correctly but it is not showing the image at the desired shape.**

```
    // MARK: - Add Image function

      func AddImage(){
          isEditingEnabled = false
          let path = UIBezierPath()
              
              // Iterate through the sphere nodes array
              for (index, nodes) in nodes.enumerated() {
                  let position = nodes.position
                  
                  if index == 0 {
                      // Move to the starting position
                      path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: CGFloat(position.y)))
                  } else {
                      // Add a line segment to the next sphere node
                      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: CGFloat(position.y)))
                      
                  }
              }
              path.close()
          
      let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.01)
      shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "grass1")
      let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
          shapeNode.position.z = -0.2
          sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)
      }
    
    
    
    
    

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            // get current hit position
            // and check if start-node is available
            if isEditingEnabled {
                
                guard let currentPosition = self.doHitTestOnExistingPlanes(),
                      let start = self.startingNode else {
                    return
                    
                }
                self.lineNode?.removeFromParentNode()
                self.lineNode = LineNode(from: start.position, to: currentPosition, lineColor: UIColor.systemBlue)
                self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.lineNode!)
            }
            else {
                self.lineNode?.removeFromParentNode()

            }
            
            
        }
    }
 
    func doHitTestOnExistingPlanes() -> SCNVector3? {
        
        let screenPoint = CGPoint(x: sceneView.bounds.midX, y: sceneView.bounds.midY)
        guard let raycastQuery = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: screenPoint, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any) else {return nil }
        
        let raycastResults = sceneView.session.raycast(raycastQuery)
        
        guard let firstResult = raycastResults.first  else {  return nil }
        // get vector from transform
        let hitPos = SCNVector3.positionFrom(matrix: firstResult.worldTransform)
        return hitPos
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

**Extra class to Add line between the nodes**

```
    class LineNode: SCNNode{

   
    init(from vectorA: SCNVector3, to vectorB: SCNVector3, lineColor color: UIColor) {
        super.init()
        let height = self.distance(from: vectorA, to: vectorB)
        self.position = vectorA
        let nodeVector2 = SCNNode()
        nodeVector2.position = vectorB
        let nodeZAlign = SCNNode()
        nodeZAlign.eulerAngles.x = Float.pi/2
        let box = SCNBox(width: 0.003, height: height, length: 0.001, chamferRadius: 0)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = color
        box.materials = [material]
        let nodeLine = SCNNode(geometry: box)
        nodeLine.position.y = Float(-height/2) + 0.001
        nodeZAlign.addChildNode(nodeLine)
        self.addChildNode(nodeZAlign)
        self.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: nodeVector2)]
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
    }
    
    func distance(from vectorA: SCNVector3, to vectorB: SCNVector3)-> CGFloat
    {
        return CGFloat(sqrt((vectorA.x - vectorB.x) * (vectorA.x - vectorB.x) +   (vectorA.y - vectorB.y) * (vectorA.y - vectorB.y) + (vectorA.z - vectorB.z) * (vectorA.z - vectorB.z)))
        
    }
}
```

extensions used in my Code.

```
    extension SCNSphere {
        convenience init(color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat) {
            self.init(radius: radius)
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = color
            materials = [material]
            
        }
    
}

extension SCNVector3 {
    
    static func positionFrom(matrix: matrix_float4x4) -> SCNVector3 {
        let column = matrix.columns.3
        return SCNVector3(column.x, column.y, column.z)
    }
    
}
```

**One new Approach :
if we add an anchor with each sphereNode , and join them together , it is giving us a shape but not showing the image :**

```
    if anchorsList.count >= 3  {
        
        // Create a custom geometry connecting the anchor positions
        var vertices = anchorsList.map { anchor in
            SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x, anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)
        }
        // Close the shape by repeating the first vertex at the end
        vertices.append(vertices[0])
        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)
        var indices: [UInt32] = []

        // Create indices for shape fan
        for i in 1..<(vertices.count - 1) {
            indices.append(0)
            indices.append(UInt32(i))
            indices.append(UInt32(i + 1))
        }
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
        let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
   
      
        
        // Add material to the geometry
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        let image = UIImage(named: "grass1")
        
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            material.isDoubleSided = true
            geometry.materials = [material]
```

material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(2, 2, 1)

```
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
            sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
              
//            node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to show us what you're getting from your code, and explain how it's not what you want to get. Explanatory images would help... as would a [mre].

Comment: Okay this was my actual question but nobody helped

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157291/how-to-assign-image-to-custom-drawn-scnshape

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that question. To get help, you will almost certainly need to put together a [mre] so we can run your current code, see what the result is, and then (hopefully) offer some tips on what you need to change.

Comment: Can you help???

Comment: Jeeyaa - I *might* be able to help. It looks like an interesting task.

Comment: Can you check now , the above code doesnt have any overlay or focus square , it only draws the sphere to complete the shape . I have also added and imageView tapHandle code for you to identify the Problem . you can run the code too.

Comment: has anybody tried out the above code?

Comment: Jeeyaa ... I copied your code, added my guess at your `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` connections... and aside from seeing what the camera sees, tapping anywhere does nothing. Best thing is to put a working (minimal) project somewhere like GitHub, so we can build and install your app and see the functionality directly.

Comment: DonMag .. I have a draw Button that draw the spheres .. after 3 spheres you can click on the image to close the shape .. Can you please try again

Comment: Have you Checked it ????

Comment: Jeeyaa ... did my answer get you on your way? Or, are you still looking for help on this? see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2KhX8ARLO8

Comment: Still trying to get the correct orientation of the imageNode .. can you help a little more please?

Comment: Jeeyaa - see the **Edit 1** in my answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was lookingfor .. can you edit the code with updated one

Comment: Jeeyaa - see the **Edit 2** in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to spend some time learning about and understanding 3D geometry...

The points you are generating for your bezier path exist in 3D-space - so the node / object you generate won't be a simple "fill in the path."

The positioning / sizing / orientation / etc will also be dependent on the orientation of the device *when the AR view is initialized* ... that is, if you launch the app with your device sitting flat on the desk and *then* pick up the device and point it, your "world coordinates" will be very different than if you launch the app while holding the device vertically and/or pointed a different direction.

Anyway...

If I make a couple changes to your `AddImage()` func, including:

- use `position.z` instead of `position.y`
- create a couple materials so we can *see* the geometry
- increase the extrusion depth so we can ***understand*** the geometry that we're seeing
- use the first node as the new object's z position to help place it in the approximate desired area

This edited func:

```
func AddImage(){
    isEditingEnabled = false
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    // Iterate through the sphere nodes array
    for (index, nodes) in nodes.enumerated() {
        let position = nodes.position
        
        // use position.z instead of position.y
        
        //if index == 0 {
        //  // Move to the starting position
        //  path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: CGFloat(position.y)))
        //} else {
        //  // Add a line segment to the next sphere node
        //  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: CGFloat(position.y)))
        //}
        
        if index == 0 {
            // Move to the starting position
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: CGFloat(position.z)))
        } else {
            // Add a line segment to the next sphere node
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(position.x), y: CGFloat(position.z)))
        }
        
    }
    path.close()
    
    guard let gImg = UIImage(named: "grass1") else {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    // couple different materials so we can see the geometry of the shape

    let grassMat = SCNMaterial()
    grassMat.diffuse.contents = gImg
    
    let cyanMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    cyanMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    
    let orangeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    orangeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
    
    let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.05)

    shape.materials = [grassMat, orangeMaterial, cyanMaterial]
    
    let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)

    if let fNode = nodes.first {
        shapeNode.position.z = fNode.position.z
    }
    
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)
    
}
```

gives me these results...

After tapping Draw button 3 times:

[image]

After calling `AddImage()`:

[image]

Rotating device after node has been created / added:

[image]

Using a couple more "draw" points:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit 1**

Part of the issue with positioning and orienting the "image node" is that, once again, we're dealing with 3-Dimensional Space.

For example, if the user has placed nodes all on the same Y-plane:

[image]

it is fairly straightforward to create the shape and then rotate and position it:

[image]

However, if the Y-coordinates are NOT on the same plane, like this:

[image]

What to do? Try to create a node/object like this?

[image]

Or, do you want to place the image node at the first node's Y-coordinate?

[image]

In that case, the first node placed was the highest node...

So, one option might be to take the *average* of the Y-Coordinates:

[image]

If this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2KhX8ARLO8 - looks close to what you're going for, I can update this answer with some additional code.

---

**Edit 2**

Assuming we have these materials setup as class properties:

```
// couple different materials so we can see the geometry of the shape
var grassMat: SCNMaterial = {
    let m = SCNMaterial()
    guard let img = UIImage(named: "grass") else {
        fatalError("Could not load grass image!")
    }
    m.diffuse.contents = img
    return m
}()
var cyanMaterial: SCNMaterial = {
    let m = SCNMaterial()
    m.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    return m
}()
var orangeMaterial: SCNMaterial = {
    let m = SCNMaterial()
    m.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
    return m
}()
```

and, assuming we've generated a valid array of nodes, your `AddImage` func might look like this:

```
func addImage() {
    
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    let xOff = nodes[0].position.x
    let zOff = nodes[0].position.z
    
    // Iterate through the sphere nodes array
    for (index, nodes) in nodes.enumerated() {
        let position = nodes.position
        
        // "normalize" the x and z coordinates
        let nx = position.x - xOff
        let nz = position.z - zOff
        if index == 0 {
            // Move to the starting position
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(nx), y: CGFloat(nz)))
        } else {
            // Add a line segment to the next sphere node
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(nx), y: CGFloat(nz)))
        }
    }
    
    path.close()
    
    let shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.001)
    
    shape.materials = [orangeMaterial, grassMat, cyanMaterial]
    
    let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)
    
    var ySum: Float = 0.0
    nodes.forEach { n in
        ySum += n.position.y
    }
    let yAvg: Float = ySum / Float(nodes.count)

    // safely unwrap optional
    if let fNode = nodes.first {
        
        // move the "normalized" shape to the first node's position
        shapeNode.position = fNode.position
        
        // move it to the average y-coordinate
        shapeNode.position.y = yAvg
    }
    
    // add the shape node
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)
    
    // rotate the shape node
    shapeNode.rotation = .init(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: .pi * 0.5)
    
}
```

---

Worth noting: it will be very easy to define a set of nodes that will give unexpected results.

For example, if the device is held vertically and we add nodes on a wall, the y-coordinates will vary greatly while the z-coordinates will have only a small variation -- resulting in a very small "shape" node.

But, making sure the user defines a valid array of nodes is outside the scope of this question.

---

I put up a sample project here: https://github.com/DonMag/ARSample

It shows several "preset" shapes... allows user-defined nodes... optionally animates the "shape node" rotation... and some other options.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted here, but I still have one more thing to do. 
i am assigning the image as SCNmaterial using the collectionView didselect, 
the issue here is  that when i draw second path , or any another shape  and select the image , it updates the previous shape node image too .

Comment: @Jeeyaa - in my example code (emphasis on ***EXAMPLE***), I created the `grassMat: SCNMaterial` once to use over and over. If you want to use different images as materials, create them when you're assigning them instead of using a single instance.

Comment: Okay done !!! Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Jeeyaa - glad you got it working... Make sure to mark the answer as "Accepted" for the benefit of other folks who may come across your question.

Comment: Already Marked! :)